# What are the differences in teachings between Yoga Vasista, Ashtavakra Gita, and Vivekachudamani?

Tags: scripture, philosophy, advaita, moksha, maya

Yoga Vasistha (योग-वासिष्ठ), Ashtavakra Gita (अष्टावक्रगीता), and Vivekachudamani (विवेकचूडामणि) are teachings about Enlightenment and (Moh)Maya. What are the Philosophical differences between these scriptures ?

Comment: Why are you adding back vidhishtadvaita and moksha tags? These texts are advaita texts not Vishishtadvaita. Question is not about moksha either. Enlightenment and moksha are different.

Comment: These texts are all related to the Advaita philosophy. So, they will have more similarities and no or less differences as far as philosophy is concerned.

Comment: 'Moksha from Maya' is the central theme of these texts, which is called Enlightenment in English Language.

Comment: Moksha is liberation and enlightenment is having knowledge or jeevanmukta. Enlightened beings are jnanis. Enlightenment doesn't mean moksha. Both are not same. We have different tags about Moksha and enlightenment which is realization according to Advaita but not according to others. Even in Advaita enlightened beings do not attain moksha.

Comment: Moksha is Liberation.
JeevanMukti is Liberation in a healthy living body.
VidehaMukti is Liberation while dying.
Moksha refers to both meanings.